# what's a good way to implement something that looks like Dictionary<string, string, Dictionary<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, generics

I've got a data structure that is Key, Value, OtherValues(key, Value). So the OtherValues are attached to the first Key and aren't always there. I can do this as `Dictionary<Key, ValueAndListOfOptionalValues>` where ValueAndListOfOptionalValues is a class with a string and a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

I'm wondering if that's really the best way to do it? Sometimes I think that I'm missing some important classes in the Generics namespace, maybe there are better classes out there that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, would use your "custom class" approach.

However, if you want to avoid a custom class (even though there's no reason to avoid it) you could do:

```
 Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string,Dictionary<string,string>>>
```

It's just awfully ugly...

Comment: Good point, I've got to consider code readability too. Just because you can do it in one line doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Yeah - this works, but it's really, really ugly.  I'd refactor this into a custom class ASAP, if it were my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a perfectly acceptable solution.  As long as you will never need to look up anything from `OtherValues` from the main `Dictionary` this should work fine and not incur any performance issues.